# How can I detect stack overflow in a command line app. written in C++ on macos?

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, stack-overflow

I have an xcode project, code is in C++. I have pinpointed in a recursive function the cause of a not normal program behave, too many stuff o the stack...
I wont to be sure that the problem is a stack overflow restoring bad stuff and set a trap to stack overflow.
How can I do this?

For now I have found "-fstack-protector-all" for clang but I can't know what is happened once prog. has run. Also I have found "-fsanitize=" but I don't know what write after the '='.

Thanks.

Comment: Run it inside a debugger (`lldb` or `gdb`).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure method to find a stack overflow.
The best method you can try to put some "MAGIC" value at the top of the stack and at every new method call check that this "MAGIC" value is still there, in the previous, and has not been overrun.

Comment: How can I know the lowest stack address?

Comment: You don't need to know the address. You simply put an unused variable as the first variable in the stack and initialize it to a certain value. You then only have to check whether the value is what is expected.

Comment: @MartijnOtto: that doesn't work... the stack grows away from the "first" variable you put on it... what's of interest is whether you reach the other end, where it can't grow any more (which this answer refers to as the "top"): doing so will not - in general - do anything to data elsewhere on the stack. (it would normally manifest as either a SIGSEGV if the past-the-stack memory is inaccessible, or start overwriting other program data at random).